# Example of generated sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I looked at the definition of a generated $\sigma$-algebra in wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) and would like to know if this is correct.

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $F=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$. Is it correct that $\sigma(F)=\{\emptyset,\{1,2,3,4\},\{1\},\{2,3,4\},\{2\},\{1,3,4\}\}$? Thanks.

edit: The correct answer is $\sigma(F)=\{\emptyset,\{1,2,3,4\},\{1\},\{2,3,4\},\{2\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$.

Comment: No, $\sigma$ algebras are closed under countable unions!

Comment: Where is {3,4}, for example?

Comment: Yes, after reading Crostul's comment I noticed that I have mistakenly left some sets out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed
$$\{ 3,4 \} = \{ 1,3,4 \} \cap  \{ 2,3,4 \}$$
and
$$\{ 1,2 \} = \{ 1 \} \cup  \{ 2 \}$$
Adding these two, you get a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice this! Many thanks.